# Softlayer GET API "VirtualGuests" response too big

Tags: api, cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, jclouds

I am trying to do a GET operation on

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/VirtualGuests?objectMask=powerState%3BoperatingSystem.passwords%3Bdatacenter%3BbillingItem%3BblockDevices.diskImage%3BtagReferences

> Headers: Authorization: Accept : application/json

Response:
{
  "error": "Internal Error",
  "code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
}
```

I found out that the results is too big, If I do a resultLimit on the API it works.

My question is, I have instance Id with me how Can I include it in the above API. I tried adding &id=XXXXXX at the end of the API it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to get only the data which contains the instance with ID correct?

well if you want the VM whose id = instace ID you can use  the Softlayer_Virtual_Guest::getObject method instead Softlayer_Account::getVirtualGuests

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getObject

If you are looking for something more complex you can try objectFilters
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters

if you have more questions let me know.